# child constructor

Tags: c#, object, constructor, parent-child

ok so this problem has been solved but all the solutions really only work in simple programs and i hope to find a more efficient way to do this. so lets assume I have this code

```
public class Parent
{
    int one;
    int two;
    public Parent(int A, int B)
    {
        one = A;
        two = B;
    }
}
public class Child : Parent
{
    int three;
    int four;
    public Child(int C, int D)
    {
        three = C;
        four = D;
    }
}
```

ok so the Child has all of the parents variables as well as all of its new variables (it has int one and two as well as three and four). when I create a child object

```
Child myChild = new Child(3,4);
```

I am only able to put in the two values stated in the child constructor and I really need to set all four variable values ( the two from the parent and the two from the child). the only solution to this i found was something along the lines of

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    int three;
    int four;
    public Child(int A, int B, int C, int D) : base(A, B)
    {
        three = C;
        four = D;
    }
}
```

however I'm dealing with dozens of children classes and around 30 parent variables and therefore the solution above gets REALLY big and any changes done to the Parent variables has to then manually be changed in EVERY child class. Is there an easy way to have the parents constructor get taged onto the child constructor or some other solution that is more efficient than that proposed above?

Comment: What do you mean "dozens of children classes and around 30 parent variables"? You seem to not understand how inheritance works.

Comment: When you get to this point then you should consider revising your class structure.

Comment: Change the fields like `int three;` to properties like so: `int three { get; protected set; }`. Then you can set themin the child constructors.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens he is already able to do it but he doesn't want to pass values to the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the fields public, remove the constructors, define whatever numbers of members, declare your classes like:

```
public class Parent {
    public int one;
    public int two;
}

public class Child: Parent {
    public int three;
    public int four;
}
```

and instantiate it like

```
var child=
    new Child {
        one=1,
        two=2,
        three=3,
        four=4
    };
```

Comment: I don't see any improvements.

Comment: @wRAR: Doesn't OP find a way that he can change the parent class without child class changed but still pass values to the fields?

Comment: Even if you think the OP asked about this, how is your answer related to this?

Comment: @wRAR: The child classes do not need to be changed for the reason that the declared fields get more and more in the parent class.

Comment: What do you mean "The child classes do not need to be changed"?

Comment: @wRAR: That is, if you declared a `public int zero;` in the parent class afterwards, you will need to do nothing with the child classes.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, that's a viable interpretation of the original question, though I'm not sure the solution is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

if you are

> dealing with dozens of children classes and around 30 parent variables

You have serious problems with your architecture. I could suggest that you read about composition over inheritance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance or [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

But if you can't do anything about it I suggest to you to group this *Parent variables* in one object and pass this object in the constructor.